# Prove If $X_{n} \rightarrow_{\text {a.e. }} X,$ then $X=\tilde{X}$ a.e. for some measurable $\tilde{X}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots$ be measurable functions from $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ to $(\bar{R}, \overline{\mathcal{B}})$
>
> 1. If $X_{n} \rightarrow_{\text {a.e. }} X,$ then $X=\tilde{X}$ a.e. for some measurable $\tilde{X}$.
> 2. If $X_{n} \rightarrow_{a.e}$  $X$ and $\mu$ is complete, then $X$ itself is measurable.

This is an exercise from textbook *Probability for Statisticians*. Our teacher provides a brief scatch of the proof by pointing we can let $\tilde{X}=X1_{N^C}$.

So $X_n1_{N^C}\rightarrow\tilde{X}$. Since $X_n$ and $1_{N^C}$ are both measurable, so will their product and the limit.

For the second part, simply consider $X=\tilde{X}+X1_N$. $X1_N$ is measurable since $$\{w:(X1_N)(\omega)<x\}=\{X<x\}\cap N\quad\text{if }x\leq0$$
$$\{w:(X1_N)(\omega)<x\}=(\{X<x\}\cap N)\cup N^c\quad\text{if }x\leq0.$$

My question is:

For the first part of the question, can I simply do the same thing by writing

$$\{w:(X1_{N^c})(\omega)<x\}=\{X<x\}\cap N^c\quad\text{if }x\leq0$$
$$\{w:(X1_{N^c})(\omega)<x\}=(\{X<x\}\cap N^c)\cup N\quad\text{if }x>0.$$

To my understanding, measurable almost everywhere means $X$ is measurable except for $\mu(B)=0$. I think I am not quite what's the meaning of the first part of the question, are we trying to  show though $X$ may not be measurable when the measure goes to $0$ but $\tilde{X}$ is measurable even when $\mu(\tilde{X})=0$, and $X_n\rightarrow_{a.e.}X=\tilde{X}$ means we care only when $\mu(\tilde{X})\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is somehow subtle and probably you'll never have to worry about it.

Let's say we have $X_1,X_2,...$ measurable from $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ to some measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$

Convergence almost surely means that set $B:=\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) $ exists $\}$ satisfies $\mu(B)=1$ (note that this set is always measurable when we go to $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ since $\mathbb R$ is complete (with usual metric)). Call this limit for $\omega \in B$ a $X(\omega)$ and let $Y=X1_{B} + 1_{B^c}$ be a limit function.

If $\sigma-$field $\mathcal A$ is not complete, then you can have non-measurable set $A$ such that $A \supset B$.

Then letting our limit to be function $\omega \to Y(\omega)1_{A}(\omega) = X(\omega)1_{B}(\omega) + 1_{A \setminus B}(\omega)$ gives us a non-measurable version of limit (because of non-measurability of set $A \setminus B$). It is indeed a limit function, since for $\omega \in B$ we have $X_n(\omega) \to Y(\omega)1_{A}(\omega) = Y(\omega)$ due to $\omega \in B \subset A$. However, since limit of number sequence is unique, if you have $X_n \to Z$ almost surely for function $Z$, you need to have $Z(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for any $\omega \in B$ (since for such $\omega$ we have $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$). Then clearly limit function $\bar{X} = X(\omega)1_{B}$ will satisfy $\bar{X}=Z$ almost surely for any such limit function $Z$ (which may be not measurable) and moreover $\bar{X}$ is a measurable version of limit.

However, if $\sigma-$field $\mathcal A$ is complete, then any set $A$ such that $A \supset B:=\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) $ exists $\}$ is measurable and moreover $\mu(A) = 1$ via monotonicisty of $\mu$. In that case, any limit function $X$ such that $X_n \to X$ almost surely can be rewritten as $X=X1_B + X1_{B^c}$ (which you've done). Then $X1_B$ is measurable due to being a pointwise limit of measurable functions $X_n1_{B}$ and $X1_{B^c}$ is measurable, since (again, as you written) preimages of sets $\{\omega \in \Omega : X1_{B^c}(\omega) \le x \}$ are either a subset of $B^c$ or have $B$ as a subset (which means due to completeness of $\mathcal A$ that those preimages are measurable and moreover have either $0$ or $1$ $\mu-$measure).